# Why doesn't ++i || ++j && ++k give the expected value

Tags: c

I want to know why the value of k is 1 in the below code.

I think `++i || ++j && ++k` is executed along the order:

```
((++i || ++j) && ++k)
```

So, in the first fragment, `(++i || ++j)`, `++i` is true, so `++j` is not evaluated, so `i=2`, `j=1`.
Next, in the second fragment, `(true && ++k)`, so `++k` is evaluated, and then `k=2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;

    i = 1; j = 1; k = 1;
    printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

But,

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
```

shows

```
2 1 1
```

I don't know what was mistaken or what I've misunderstood.

Comment: Look up "short-circuit evaluation".

Comment: What makes you think the first statement is executed in the order that you think? Because … it isn’t.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  OP actually described short-circuit evaluation with the text *" so* `++j` *is not evaluated"*.  That is not the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting!

Comment: @abelenky Um.. right. But I guess that reading would be beneficial anyway :)

Comment: @mch The OP seems aware of short circuit behavior. The problem here is that they aren't aware of the operator precedence. Not a duplicate.

Comment: It does. More sense would be to ask, how is it evaluated :) Operator precedence, prefix addition and shortcircuiting all come into play here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The logical AND operator `&&` has higher precedence than the logical OR operator `||`.  So the expression is actually parsed as:

```
++i || (++j && ++k)
```

`++i` evaluates to true so the entire right side of the `||`, i.e. `++j && ++k`, is not evaluated.  This results in neither `j` nor `k` being incremented.

It can be difficult to remember all the precedence rules, both for yourself and for others who read your code.  So when in doubt, use parenthesis to clarify your intentions.

Comment: [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for operator precedence, shows `&&` at 11, and `||` at 12.

Comment: Oh... my textbook didn't tell me anything about precedence between && and ||. Thank you for help !!

Comment: And your Reference link is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: “It can be difficult to remember all the precedence rules” — Absolutely, but you should know (and presuppose in readers) *at the very least* BODMAS. Adding redundant parentheses for these operations doesn’t add clarity, it adds clutter. I’m tempted to add the precedence of logical `||` and `&&` to that list.

Comment: @김재우: Important note - precedence only controls how expressions are *parsed*, not the order in which they are evaluated.  The `||` and `&&` operators are two of the four operators that force left-to-right evaluation (the others being `?:` and the comma operator).  For all other operators (arithmetic, relational, etc.), order of evaluation is *unspecified*.  An expression like `a + b * c` is *parsed* as `a + (b * c)` because `*` has higher precedence than `+`, but the expressions `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order* relative to each other.

Comment: This looks like a test question. If someone wrote code like in that example they are gonna have a nice talking to with a reviewer (certainly you would get one from me). As a test of knowledge, fine, but one should fear using extra parenthesis when it makes it more readable. Evensome read your code right in 10 seconds, it might take someone 5 minutes or make someone to fire up the StackOverflow after half an hour spent on it. Keep in mind good code is written once but it might be read dozens of times, spend the time to make it readable for diff levels of developers.

Answer (score 4):

Running with compiler warnings, or a good editor like [Atom.io](https://atom.io), reveals the problem.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`   -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:8:30: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);
                      ~~ ~~~~^~~~~~
test.c:8:30: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
    printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);
                             ^
                         (         )
1 warning generated.
```

It's a precedence issue. Operators in an expression are not evaluated left-to-right but rather in precedence order. `++i || ++j && ++k` is being evaluated as `++i || (++j && ++k)` because [`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

To avoid these issues, turn on compiler warnings and make it a habit to put parens around anything that might be ambiguous.

Comment: I can't understand your code because I am beginner. But I can understand the precedence between && and ||. Thank you for help !

Comment: @김재우 it’s a compiler invocation and output shown, not code. Schwern is compiling your code and asking for warnings about possible problems. The compiler kindly suggests a potential problem and a fix.